# Dynamically filter data in nested javascript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamic array `var arr = ["key1","key2","key3"]`
i want to filter an array of objects with this array,for example,

```
var obj = [{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":5}}},{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":7}}},{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":8}}}]
```

with "key3" equals to 5. How can I achieve this with vanilla javascript?

Comment: what I want to check is obj.filter(e => e["key1"]["key2"]...etc = some_value); but the elements in the array can vary

Comment: Post at least two example of input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the keys with the object and return the value for checking.

```js
var getValue = (keys, object) => keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object),
    keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
    array = [{ key1: { key2: { key3: 5 } } }, { key1: { key2: { key3: 7 } } }, { key1: { key2: { key3: 8 } } }],
    result = array.filter(o => getValue(keys, o) === 5);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```